# JavaScript to remove object with ajax (destroy.js.erb) not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 app I am allowing users to add awards to their profiles. Using Rails UJS I get the `create` working with ajax. However, I can't for the life of me get `destroy` to work. Looking inside my server log, it looks like it's working, but the `@award` isn't removed unless I refresh my profile page.

The code I used is from a tutorial I was following in [Beginning Rails 3](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?client=safari&rls=en&q=rails%203%20book&oe=UTF-8&um=1&hl=en&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=664&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=10269874108050999480&sa=X&ei=V0MOT7HTHuLt0gGW3KS-Aw&ved=0CHEQ8wIwAw#ps-sellers). If anyone can help me figure out what's going on wrong in my code I'd appreciate it.

My `awards_controller.rb`:

```
def create
  @award = Award.new(params[:award])
  if @award.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      #format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@profile) }
      format.js { }
    end
  else
    respond_to do |format|
      #format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@profile)}
      format.js { render 'fail_create_award.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end

def destroy
  @award = Award.find(params[:id])
  @award.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    #format.html { redirect_to profile_path(@profile) }
    format.js { render :nothing => true }
  end
end
```

My `create.js.erb`:

```
$('ul#awardInfo').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(@award)) %>");
$('#new_award')[0].reset();
```

My `destroy.js.erb`:

```
$("ul#awardInfo<%= (@award) %>").remove();
```

My form to delete the award, which appears as an "x" next to the award if the award belongs to/was created by the `current_user`:

```
<li>-&nbsp;<%= award.body %><% if @profile = current_user.profile %><span class="delete"><%= link_to 'x', award_path(award), :method => :delete, :remote => true, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to remove this award?", :class => "delete_award" %></span><% end %></li>
```

In my server log when I click "delete" (but before refreshing the page):

```
Started DELETE "/awards/8" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-11 21:34:58 -0500
  Processing by AwardsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"8"}
  Award Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "awards".* FROM "awards" WHERE "awards"."id" = '8' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.4ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"awards"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

  AREL (0.6ms)  DELETE FROM "awards" WHERE "awards"."id" = 8
  SQL (2.3ms)  COMMIT
Rendered text template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 31ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 5.4ms)
```

**UPDATE:** If I remove `render :nothing => true` from my destroy action, it doesn't actually remove the award. My log shows the following:

```
Started DELETE "/awards/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-03 07:54:34 -0500
  Processing by AwardsController#destroy as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"3"}
  Award Load (238.1ms)  SELECT "awards".* FROM "awards" WHERE "awards"."id" = '3' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.6ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"awards"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum
  AREL (97.3ms)  DELETE FROM "awards" WHERE "awards"."id" = 3
  SQL (45.8ms)  COMMIT
Rendered awards/destroy.js.erb (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 954ms (Views: 531.9ms | ActiveRecord: 383.2ms)
```

**UPDATE 2:** So a weird thing happens if I go to check the HTML:

- If I view source, I don't actually see any of the awards.
- If I inspect the element, I see the following:
  `<li>-&nbsp;test<span class="delete"><a href="/awards/4" class="delete_award" data-confirm="Are you sure you want to remove this award?" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">x</a></span></li>`

The `<li>` is the actual award created. I have an `award.rb` model that `belongs_to :profile`. If the profile awards belong to my profile, I see a delete option, which is what the `<span>` is for.

Answer (score 4):

Putting `format.js { render :nothing => true }` in your `destroy` action is presumably telling Rails to **not** render your **destroy.js.erb**.

Using the same `format.js { }` as used in the `create` action should direct Rails to render **destroy.js.erb** and subsequently execute the desired action.

**Update**:

From the code above, it looks like there's nothing in the actual award HTML that can be used to select on for the `remove` call.

I'd recommend making sure the `li` elements include ID attributes with the award ID in them.  Something like:

```
<li id="award-<%= @award.id %>">
```

Then, to remove the award, select its `li` element and remove as follows:

```
$('li#award-<%= @award.id %>').remove();
```

It looks to me like the only remaining issue is that the jQuery call isn't selecting the right element, or any element at all, to call remove on.  Giving the `li` a unique ID and then selecting that ID for removal *should* make the destroy action render properly.

Comment: Unfortunately taking out `render :nothing => true` didn't do the trick.

Comment: Did doing so alter the `Rendered text template` line in your log?  When you do a `render :nothing => true`, Rails renders an empty text template.  Just doing `format.js` should have changed what Rails is rendering, and if so, I can probably provide more help if I see what's being rendered now.

Comment: I've updated my question with what the log shows. Now at least my `destroy.js.erb` is being rendered. So it must be what's in that file?

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to remove a **ul** element, when really you want to be removing an **li** element.  Since element IDs are supposed to be unique across an entire document, you really shouldn't even need a specific tag selector.  You can just fetch the element you want to remove by its ID, like: `$("awardInfo<%= (@award) %>").remove()`.  I'm actually not sure what's contained in @award.  Is it a model, or just an ID?  What does the actual HTML of your awards look like after **create** has run?

Comment: Edited further above to answer your questions.